# Sum the number of Leads for each Country?

Tags: joined-reports

I have a report that shows the number of countries that exist in Leads,

How can I show the number of Leads available for each Country?

Ex:

```
    Country
    Unites States
    Canada
    France
    UK
    Unites States
    France
    Unites States
    Unites States
    UK

    So 
    Country         No of Leads
    Unites States      4
    France             2
    UK                 2
    Canada             1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a summary report and group by Country then you have the number of leads per country.

[image]

[image]

Comment: To be honest, thats what i did, but it keeps on adding all the fields, how did you remove all the fields and get the example above?

Comment: you need to click on Show and then switch of details. see my screenshot in my answer

Comment: Can you please tell me how to add numbers in front of each country? so i can see the number of countries without counting them. For example, with your image you have 1,2,3, and 4.

Comment: hmm i don't think that is possible at the moment, there is an idea already for that so maybe it will come in later releases.